# Saving Strings to Files

Tags: perl

When I save a string to a file, and than load it back from the same file, it acts differently from the original string.

It seems that the first code with the hardcoded ip address works, but the second code where I write to the file and than read back, won't work. If I print $ip after loading from the file, it looks the same.

```perl
$ip = "100.10.100.1";
$port = 1337;
socket(S,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname("tcp"));
connect(S,sockaddr_in($port,inet_aton($ip)));
```

```perl
$ip = "100.10.100.1";

my $filename = 'c:\\tmp\\ip.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename);
print $fh "$ip";
close $fh;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename);
$i = 0;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    if ($i eq 0) {
        $ip = $row;
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}

$port = 1337;
socket(S,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname("tcp"));
connect(S,sockaddr_in($port,inet_aton($ip)));
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `use Devel::Peek qw(Dump); ……… Dump $ip;` after reading it from the file. –– Just as a basic sanity check, add the usual `use strict; use warnings; use autodie;` to the program and see whether that uncovers hidden problems.

Comment: What does "it acts differently from the original string" mean? Exactly what unexpected behaviour do you see?

Comment: @DaveCross - the first snippet connects successfully. In the second, I don't get a connection. I can't see the output of the script, only write log lines to a file

Comment: @daxim - I can't see the standard output and error of the program. When I try to run the script in a regular perl environment where I can see the output, it works and connects successfully

Comment: @tom, redirect STDERR into a file: `open *STDERR, ">>", "/tmp/STDERR.log";`

Comment: The file gets created and has the content you expect?   Neither open() here is necessarily working because you don't catch errors from it.

Comment: @stevesliva - yeah, the file contains the ip address and nothing but the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems that the perl was run with -T cmd line option, which means it runs in "taint mode" and distrust data it read from files.

When printing the errors to a file, I saw a warning
"Insecure dependency in connect while running with -T switch"

Thanks for the tips!